# Fill ProgressBar by value/width of other ProgressBars

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am generating first four buttons and progress bar dynamically(Java,CPP,Csharp & functional). I am adding width/value to them using javascript/jquery. Now i want to add width/value of all those progress bar to mainProgreeBar after clicking on finish button. Here is my JavaScript code, and Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Yfr/)about same

**JS**

```
   function showSummery(){
    $("#summeryDiv").show();

    var finalScore= 0;
    $( "#subjdiv" ).next( ".btn",function(){
              var a = $(".btn").val();
          finalScore =parseInt($('#Javaprogressbar').val());
     });

     // finalScore  = finalScore +$( "#subjdiv" )
     // .nextUntil( '.progress-bar', 'div')
     // .width();
    alert(finalScore);
    $('#mainProgressBar').css(
        "width",finalScore+"%"
    );
    document.getElementById('#mainProgressBar').innerHTML=finalScore+"%";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function showSummery(){
      var inputValues;
      $('.final').each(function() {
        var type = $(this).attr("value");
        inputValues = inputValues + type;
      })
     alert(inputValues);
     $('#mainProgressBar').css("width",inputValues+"%");
    }
```

This is working for me